# $uibModal close automatically

Tags: angularjs

How can I close the modal to 3 seconds automatically, if the user does not press any modal option?
If the user does nothing, it will automatically close

Thank you

```
$uibModal.open({
      backdrop: 'static',
      templateUrl: 'app/components/genericConfirmModal/generic-confirm-dialog.html',
      controller: 'GenericModalAcceptController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      size: 'md',
      resolve: {
        title: function() {
          return 'Anulación ticket';
        },
        icon: function() {
          return 'ok';
        },
        message: function() {
          return 'El ticket se ha anulado con éxito';
        },
        buttonMessage: function() {
          return 'Aceptar';
        }
      }
    }).result.then(function() {
      $state.go('catalog', {}, {
        reload: true
      });
    }, function() {
      $state.go('catalog', {}, {
        reload: true
      });
    });
```

Comment: using $timeout, in ypur own controller when is opened

Comment: Do you know you should accept best answer to make community effective, if somebody searching same problem they will see the best answer first. Please accept one of below answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a $timeout:

```
var timer = $timeout(function () {
    // Close your modal here
}, 3000);
```

If you want to cancel closing, you can use:

```
$timeout.cancel(timer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout):

```
$timeout(function() {
   $uibModal.close(); // Not sure of this synthax
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just setup a time of 3 seconds and close Modal

```
$scope.cancel = cancel;
function cancel() {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    $timeout.cancel(time);
}

var time = $timeout(function () {
   cancel();
}, 3000);
```